# Javascript minimize and maximize

Tags: javascript

I want to scale the div onclick to 25% and back onclick to 50%.
Why isn't it scaling back to 50%?

```
var minimize = document.getElementById('minimize');
var container = document.getElementById('container');

minimize.onclick = function(){

    if(container.style.width = "50%") {
        container.style.width = "25%";
        container.style.height = "25%";
    }else{
        container.style.width = "50%";
        container.style.height = "50%";
    }

    console.log(container.style.width);
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an assignment rather than a comparison in your if statement:

```
if (container.style.width = "50%") {
```

Should be:

```
if (container.style.width == "50%") {
```

The assignment will return the assigned value - "50%". That value is truthy, so the code inside the if statement will be executed.